# Which is the best transport from Hyderabad to Srisailam?

Tags: hyderabad

I am planning for a short trip from Hyderabad to Srisailam this weekend with my family, please suggest some good means of transport.

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 direct bus traveling between [**`Hyderabad to Srisailam`**](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Hyderabad,+Telangana/Srisailam,+Andhra+Pradesh+518101/@16.6391428,78.3985761,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x3bcb99daeaebd2c7:0xae93b78392bafbc2!2m2!1d78.486671!2d17.385044!1m5!1m1!1s0x3bb5656d70792343:0xb2342e1f2ed1834b!2m2!1d78.8687291!2d16.0732748!3e0)( Via-> NH765 and SH 5. Fare-> ₹385). The minimum time a bus takes to reach Srisailam from Hyderabad within 7 Hours. It will be better if you hire a private car from your source place.

Answer (score 0):

With family, it would be a good idea to hire a private car.

You can take an exit from the ORR either at RGIA and go through the airport approach road, or the one next to Airport near Sreenagar (Exit 14). Joy of renting a car is that you can take stops at sites like Dindi Reservoir, Srisailam Tiger Reserve, and Malletirtham waterfalls.